# Recover Pruned Worktree

Tags: git, git-worktree

I have multiple worktrees located on a network drive. Here's the general file system structure:

- repos

  - main repo
  - worktree 1 (network drive)
  - worktree 2 (network drive)
  - worktree X (network drive) <-- wanted to prune this one
  - worktree 3 (network drive)

During a brief network disruption where the 3 worktrees were unavailable, I pruned my worktrees intending only to get rid of worktree X. Unfortunately, all my worktrees were pruned because git couldn't find any of those directories.

Now I can access my files again, but all of git's metadata in "main repo/.git/worktrees" is gone. Attempting to recreate the pruned worktrees with `git worktree add <PATH> <BRANCH>` results in the error message `<PATH> already exists`. Looking at the information that git normally stores that, I don't think it would be a good idea to manually recreate those files. Googling this only gave me questions where people still had their metadata but had deleted the source files, which is the opposite of my problem.

Is there a way to "recover" the pruned worktrees? IE, recreate the lost metadata or allow git to rediscover the other directories? I have unstaged/uncommitted changes on those other directories that I would like to try to recover if at all possible.

**EDIT:**
The staged changes were preserved in the source repo on the branches, since workareas share their branches.